# Android EditText with line

Tags: android

I am looking to define an `EditText` with a line right under the text.

I have defined this piece of code to achieve this. Whilst it fits its purpose, I am wondering whether or not this is the best way to achieve this.

First, I have defined a shape in a drawable XML file called `text_item_layout.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape"line">
    <padding android:bottom="20dp" />
    <stroke android:width="match_parent" android:color="@color/my_color"/>
</shape>
```

Then, I have defined style `edit_text_style` for the `EditText`:

```
<style name="my_edit_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:texdtSize">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_item_layout</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114859/android-edittext-underline

Answer (score 0):

try

yourEditText.setPaintFlags(yourEditText.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);