# EditText: how to underline all Text in an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, underline

I am working on editText with some button for: bold, italic, and underline. I've had success with bold and italic, but I don't know how to underline text.

My purpose is while typing in editText, and the underline button is press, then all text is underlined.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361755/android-how-to-make-all-lines-in-an-edittext-underlined

Comment: thanks for this. but  it just underline text after click the underline button.(it mean, after the createUnderlinedText() is process )
what i want is when typing, it automatically underlined (same as bold or italic)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4537922/1849482 i thnk it might help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my [RichEditText](https://github.com/kemallette/RichEditText) library. It has all the functionality you want and a lot more.