# How do i make underlines in multiline EditText in xml Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="0"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

i would like to put page lines in this edit Text.

like this page

[image]

Comment: You can see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537922/9060113

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - edittext - underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114859/android-edittext-underline)

Comment: Those are 7 years old they are using Eclipse. i am new to programming and i am using android Studio if someone can help i will appreiciate, thanks